# Can't pass an item from a list to a function with Typescript & React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a component that loops through and array to make a list, and I want to be able to click an item and then add that to the state of the component:

```
<ul className="results-container">
  {results.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li className="_item"
        key={index}
        onClick={this._handleSelect}
      >
      {item.suburb} {item.postcode}
      </li>
     )
   })}
 </ul>
```

My `_handleSelect` function is where I want to do the logic (I'm just trying to log it out:

```
_handleSelect = (event: MouseEvent): void => {
  console.log(event);
}
```

I'm always getting type warnings like this:

```
Type '(event: FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>'.
       Types of property 'currentTarget' are incompatible.
         Type 'EventTarget & HTMLLIElement' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget & HTMLSelectElement'.
```

(And about 50 others)

I've searched for every combination I can on Google and nothing answers my question. The closest I have got is the have the function in the list be `_handleSelect(item)` and the function the be `_handleSelect = (item: any) =>` which did manage to log the items out, but would shortly crash.

`event: MouseEvent` returns the class that is attached to the item in the list, which has not target or value properties.

**Updated Question**

With the help of some of the answers below and a bit more hacking, I've gotten to a point where I get it too work, I just have a single TS error, which stops the app from compiling (Storybook is fine). I've broken the question down to it's basic component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface Props {
  /** Array of objects that make up the selection options */
  options: any[];
  /** The object key that shows in the list and displayed when something is selected */
  optionKey: string;
};

interface Item {
  suburb: string;
  postcode: number;
  storeName: string;
}

interface State {
  value?: Item
}

export default class BasicLoop extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: undefined
    }
  }

  _handleSelect = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>): void => {
    const selection = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('value');
    const parsed: Item = JSON.parse(selection) // <--- The error is on underlined on the selection variable.
    this.setState({
      value: parsed
    }, () => console.log(this.state))
  }

  render() {
    const {
      optionKey,
      options,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
          <ul>
            {options.map((item, index) => (
              <li
                onClick={this._handleSelect}
                key={index}
                value={JSON.stringify(item)}>
                <span>{item[optionKey]}</span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Hovering on the JSON.parse(selection) where the error is returns:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

The value of selection is a string when it comes from the list, which I then parse to a new variable with the Item definition and the setState with that. The error underlines the `selection` in the parse function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure But If you want to use item  in your _handleSelect function . you could do something like this:

```
<ul className="results-container">
  {results.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li className="_item"
        key={index}
        onClick={(event: MouseEvent) => {this._handleSelect(item)}}
      >
      {item.suburb} {item.postcode}
      </li>
     )
   })}
 </ul>
```

Frankly speaking there are more typescript errors in this case, which i think can be solved once you resolves this issue.

If this is not what you wanted, Please add more code to the question 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, so here are my best guess: Type of event for li element, can be React.FormEvent[HTMLInputElement]

```
_handleSelect = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
}
```

and you need to specify a value in li element

```
<ul className="results-container">
  {results.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li className="_item"
        key={index}
        onClick={this._handleSelect}
        value={something}
      >
      {item.suburb} {item.postcode}
      </li>
     )
   })}
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is what I'm looking for, to pas that value back to the state of the form (it's a fuzzy search input).

I implemented your suggestion, and the warning is still there, and it just returned a `0`. I also changed it too `event: React.FormEvent<HTMLLIElement>`, which removed the warning, but also returned a `0`

Comment: UPDATE: Inspecting the element shows `value="[object Object]"`

Comment: It returns 0 because the value is not specified, you need to add value in li element. for example value={123}.

Comment: I have a value added to the li element: `value={`${item.suburb} ${item.postcode}`}`. But even when I just pass in a normal string like `value="test"` it will still return `0`

Comment: You may use data-value={'your value here'} in li and get it by event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-value').